# I am not able to get values of two input box when corresponding checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This code successfully prints the checkbox value. However both input values show as `undefined`. How can I achieve this?

```
<tbody>
  {% for i in allData %}
    <tr class="checkRowedit">
      <td><label>{{i.0}}</label></td>
      <td><input name="component" type="text" value="{{i.1}}"></td>
      <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="{{i.2}}"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{i.0}}"></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}           
</tbody>
```

```js
$('.checkRowedit').on('change', ':checkbox', function () { 
  index = values.indexOf(this.value);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log($(this).val() + ' input enabled');

    comp_temp  = $(this).children(':input[name="component"]').value;
    plan_temp = $(this).children(':input[name="plans"]').value;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the 'component' and 'plans' input elements are not children of the checkbox, so the DOM traversal logic is incorrect. They are instead grandchildren of the parent `tr`. As such you can use a combination of `closest()` and `find()` to retrieve them.

Also note that you need to use the `val()` method to get their values, not the `value` property. Try this:

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var comp_temp  = $tr.find(':input[name="component"]').val();
var plan_temp = $tr.find(':input[name="plans"]').val();
```

Comment: still not able to get it

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following code

```
$("table").on('change', '.checkRowedit', function(event){
    /* console.log(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.childrenElement) */;
  tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  component = tr.find('input[name="component"]').val();
  plans = tr.find('input[name="plans"]').val();
  console.log(component + " " + plans);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s69nqh1w/17/

Comment: THANK YOU. Works

Comment: I think you can use `component = $(this).find('input[name="component"]').val();
  plans = $(this).find('input[name="plans"]').val();` directly in this solution. You don't need to find closest `tr`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `.closest('tr')` to get the parent element and then `.find()` to get the "siblings" of the checkbox.

Plus, you can use `.val()` instead of `.value` in your code.

Working snippet:

```js
$('.checkRowedit').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  // index = values.indexOf(this.value); // TAKIT: I don't understand What do you want to do with this line
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.clear();
    console.log($(this).val() + ' input enabled');
    comp_temp = $(tr).find(':input[name="component"]').val(); // Using my tr variable and .val() instead of .value
    plan_temp = $(tr).find(':input[name="plans"]').val();
    console.log(comp_temp, plan_temp);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="checkRowedit">
      <td><label>{{i.0}}</label></td>
      <td><input name="component" type="text" value="{{i.1}}"></td>
      <td><input name="plans" type="text" value="{{i.2}}"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{i.0}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.